# jQuery AJAX Request Doesn't Work on Page Load, However, It Does Work from Debug Console

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**Turning off asynchronous requests in jQuery fixed the issue.**

I have the following Javascript & AJAX request (using jQuery) in my page:

```
    "use strict";

    var hsArea, counter, hotspots, count;
    counter = 4;
    count = 0;
    hotspots = {};

    function fetchHotspotList() {
        $.getJSON ('/alpha/engine/hotspots/gethotspot.php', {'type' : 'list'}, function(json) {
            hotspots = json;
        });
    }

    function displayHotspot(type, id, number) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/alpha/engine/hotspots/gethotspot.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'type' : type, 'id' : id},
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                var hotspot, extract;
                    extract = json.content;
                    extract = extract.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
                    extract = extract.substring(0, 97);
                    extract = extract + "...";
                    json.content = extract;

                    hotspot = document.createElement("div");
                    hsArea.append(hotspot);
                    hotspot.setAttribute('class','hotspot');
                    hotspot.setAttribute('id','hotspot' + number);

                    $(hotspot).css('position', 'absolute');
                    $(hotspot).css('top', number * 100 + 100);
                    $(hotspot).css('left', number * 100 + 110);

                    hotspot.innerHTML = "<h1>"+ json.title + "</h1><p>" + json.content + "</p>";
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
        }

        function listHotspots() {
            for(count = 0; count < counter; count++) {
                (function(count) {
                    displayHotspot('scribble',hotspots[count], count);
                    count = count + 1;  
                })(count);
            }
        }

        function loadHotspots() {
            fetchHotspotList();
            listHotspots();
        }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        hsArea = $("#hotspotArea");
        fetchHotspotList();
        listHotspots();
    });
```

(Sorry the formatting is a bit off!) - Now, the $(document).ready() function assigns the hsArea variable as it should, however, a combination of fetchHotspotList() and listHotspots() returns:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null`

However, if in the Google Chrome Javascript console, I run:

`loadHotspots();`

it fetches the data from the AJAX request and displays it properly on the page. At first I thought the problem was that I Wasn't using the $(document).ready() handler, but adding it hasn't fixed it. Neither has using an onload handler inside of the body tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ben.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is all encased in <script type="text/javascript></script> tags!

Comment: You are calling `replace` on `extract`. And you get `extract` from `json.content`. Check if the index `content` exists for the returned `json` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to the fact that your `listHotSpots` function is called before `fetchHotSpots` returns (since it's an async call).

You're better off chaining the execution of `listHotSpots` to the completion of `fetchHotSpots`, like so:

```
function fetchHotspotList() {
    $.getJSON ('/alpha/engine/hotspots/gethotspot.php', {'type' : 'list'}, function(json) {
        hotspots = json;
        listHotSpots();
    });
}
```

You may be better off modifying `listHotSpots` to take the json data returned from your AJAX call.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help David, however, I've turned off async calls completely for now, which fixed the issue. However, I'll try your method too!

EDIT - Just tested: this method also works!